# How to prevent flood of unwanted established connections - iptables

Tags: 20.04, iptables, netstat

There seem to be a flood of unwanted, established port 22 connections to my server. When running `sudo netstat -natup | grep 'ESTABLISHED'` as root, I get a long list of unwanted established connections, all with the same PID, that use different ports on my IP.

```
root@server:~# sudo netstat -natup | grep 'ESTABLISHED'
tcp        0      712 xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:54010    45.9.148.99:446         ESTABLISHED 51980/tsm
tcp        0      488 xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:58860    83.224.137.250:22       ESTABLISHED 51980/tsm
...and approx. 100 more
```

After I kill this process with `sudo kill -9 [PID]`, this list shows only my ssh connections for a few minutes. Then, regardless if I open a new ssh connection or close one, a new flood of new connections with port 22, all with the same PID and accessing each one of them a different port on my IP address.

For my firewall, I use iptables. With the first occurrence, I set up rules for INPUT and FORWARD that drop the connections to the specific IP address. This works but I cannot add every IP address that shows up new on the list.

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 45.9.148.99 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -I FORWARD -s 45.9.148.99 -j DROP
```

I am newbie at setting up a Ubuntu webserver. Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
In /var/log/auth.log, e.g., I see:

```
Mar 12 12:08:28 server sshd[56681]: Received disconnect from 218.75.147.238 port 51666:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 12 12:08:28 server sshd[56681]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 218.75.147.238 port 51666 [preauth]
```

I recently set up ssh keys and disabled password authentication.

Comment: Does your ssh server permit password authentication? Or is a key required? Also, review /var/log/auth.log to determine if any of those access attempts have been successful.

Comment: I recently setup ssh keys and disabled password authentication but before I used password authentication without ssh keys. Regarding the auth.log, I have disconnects from unknown users, not as many the neststat lists has 'ESTABLISHED' connections though. Why would netstat state ESTABLISHED if the connection would not be?

Comment: Your issue happens with everyone. Some use fail2ban to automatically block repeat offenders. I use the recent module in iptables directly to automatically identify and block bad guys. Search my user name with key words `iptables` and `recent` for examples, but [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366927/how-to-prevent-unauthorized-ssh-login-attempts/1366932#1366932) is a recent one. For the `ESTABLISHED` comment: Yes, the tcp connection is in that state until the bad guy is rejected by SSH, it does NOT mean they gained access.

Answer (score 1):

Every single server that has even a single open port to the internet will get targeted by bots in order to try a whole bunch of vulnerabilities.

Two common ways to better shield you :

- Install a bruteforce-combatting software, like `fail2ban` or `crowdsec`
- Change your `ssh` port to a totally random high port that will be less likely to be targeted

Comment: It'd be better to just secure your SSH port with a whitelist to permit only *certain* IPs in than leave it wide open.  Just my 2 cents